# Due to reduction of 25% in price of oranges a customer can purchase 4 oranges more for Rs. 16. What is the original price of an orange?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Due to reduction of 25% in price of oranges a customer can purchase 4 oranges more for Rs. 16. What is the original price of an orange?

What is given in the solution.
Reduction in price=$1/4$
Increase in amount=$1/3$
Based on inverse proportion 
If it is based on inverse proportion shouldn't the increase in amount be 4? Please can someone explain it

Comment: What is Rs. 16?

Comment: Indian currency

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ - old price, $y$ - number of oranges one can buy for 16 Rs. Then we have a system of equations: $xy=16$, $0.75x(y+4)=16$. Let's simplify the second equation: $0.75xy+3x=16$, $3x=16-0.75\cdot 16=4$. Thus, $x=1\frac{1}{3}$